# What is the absolute meaning of a drag coefficient of 1.0?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, viscosity

I understand the basic meaning of a drag co-efficient -- the higher it is, the more drag the object experiences when moving through a fluid.

I also understand that it's a "dimensionless quantity."

So, drag coefficient only means something in relative terms.

But who decided what 1.0 means? Is there agreement on what a drag coefficient of 1.0 represents? Was there some type of real-world analog that was used to benchmark the value of 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

The drag coefficient is just a proportionality constant. The value itself does not really matter. We know that $F_d \propto \rho u^2 A$ and we defined $F_d \equiv 2c_d \rho u^2 A$, with $c_d$ the drag coefficient. We could have equally well picked $F_d \equiv 54c_d \rho u^2 A$ and than $c_d$ would be lower, but the physics wouldn't change. :)

Comment: Is it linear? So something with a CD of 1 is half as "slippery" as something with a CD of 2?

Comment: Depends what you mean with "slippery". We are talking about a force, so $F_d = c_d \rho u^2 A = ma$. If you now take two objects in mind (object 1 and 2), which are exactly the same expect for there drag coefficient, then we see that: $ma_1 = c_{d,1}\rho u^2 A$ and $ma_2 = c_{d,2}\rho u^2 A$ so that $a_1/a_2 = c_{d,1}/c_{d,2}$. What you does can conclude is that their acceleration ratio will be the same as that of the drag coefficients.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician nor a physicist, unfortunately. What I was trying say is, will it take twice the force to move something with a CD of 2 through a liquid than something with a CD or 1?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: But there's no real-world analog or estimation of what1.0 is? They didn't fiddle with the algorithm to make 1.0 something most people would relate to?

Comment: Following wikipedia, a drag coefficient is similar to what a skier would experience, but no not really. It is however the most convenient to define it like this, because otherwise you would have to write a silly constant in the force every time.